# useNavigate won't work after removing JWT from localstorage

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

The goal is to basically "logout", which means removing the JWT that's currently stored in local storage.

Ideally, what I want is that the logout button is clicked, the logout function is dispatched which is essentially just removing the JWT from local storage, the reset function is dispatched which means that the state is reverted back to the initial state, and finally, it will navigate onto the login page via the useNavigate hook.

The problem is, it can't seem to work. Oddly enough, I tried testing out if it's reading anything on the selector

Here is the code for the dashboard, which checks if there's an existing user in local storage, and if null, redirects to the login page:

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth); 

  const { posts, isLoading, isError, message } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.post
  );

useEffect(() => {
    if (isError) {
      console.log(message);
    }

    if (!user) {
      navigate("/login");
    }

    dispatch(getPosts());

    return () => {
      dispatch(reset());
    };
  }, [user, message, isError, navigate, dispatch]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }
```

here's the logout function from the slice as well as the slice containing the reset:

```
export const logout = createAsyncThunk("auth/logout", async () => {
  await authService.logout();
});


export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.isError = false;
      state.message = "";
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(register.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(register.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.user = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(register.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
        state.user = null;
      })
      .addCase(login.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.user = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(login.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
        state.user = null;
      })
      .addCase(logout.fulfilled, (state) => {
        state.user = null;
      });
  },
});
```

Here's the function that handles the logout button click event:

```
  const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
    dispatch(reset());
    navigate("/");
  };
```

Edit:
The returned callback function in the first set of codes is basically the same all throughout, it just reverts the state into the default state (null values).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean exactly when saying it's not navigating. The app isn't navigating to `"/"` after dispatching those two actions? Where do you really want to navigate to? The `handleLogout` function navigates to `"/"` but in your post you say you want to navigate to `"/login"`.

Comment: Apologies, so the first navigate() call is for navigating the user back to the login page if there is no such instance of a user in local storage. 

The other one is for navigating to the "/" which is the main dashboard, therefore, it's supposed to navigate to the dashboard after logging out, and then the dashboard will check if there isn't any user anymore after logging out, which ultimately redirects to the login page.

Comment: So what isn't working? What is the issue you are trying to resolve? What debugging steps have been taken?

Comment: What's not working is that it's supposed to be navigating to the login page, I tried logging the user if it's actually null inside the useEffect, and it turns out it is null, but the if (!user) is not running the condition at all. So then I tried doing an if else: if(user) {console.log("User detected")} else if (!user) { console.log("No user detected")} and none of these logs ever came up.

Comment: Also, I've tried directly navigating to the /login via the handleLogout function, but it still doesn't work. Another problem is since the "/" is the default directory, at the start, nothing is showing up because the if (!user) doesn't work even if the user is null, which is responsible for redirecting to the login page in the first place..

Comment: Why not navigate to `"/login"` directly? If the `user` is falsey, and `null` is a falsey value, then the `if (!user)` condition should evaluate true and run the logic in the `useEffect` hook and navigate. Are there any errors? Can you include the `authService.logout` code?

Comment: Yes, it's weird because I've tried running an if statement on both possibilities (user and user===null) but both aren't getting triggered at all. Navigating to the login directly does nothing too, but even if it did, it still won't fix the blank page that's shown if I haven't logged in yet since the dashboard is on the "/" route.

Answer (score 0):

The `logout` action is asynchronous, and the `logout.fulfilled` action is what clears the `state.user` back to `null`. The `handleLogout` function doesn't wait for the Promise to resolve though, it just dispatches the two actions and immediately navigates to `"/"`. It's likely the case that the logout logic hasn't completed and reset the user state when the UI is checking the user state on the dashboard.

It seems that `handleLogout` should wait for the `logout` action to resolve, *then* issue the other action dispatch and navigate.

```
export const logout = createAsyncThunk("auth/logout", async () => {
  return await authService.logout(); // <-- return Promise
});
```

```
const handleLogout = async () => {
  await dispatch(logout()); // <-- await Promise to resolve
  dispatch(reset());
  navigate("/");
};
```

Comment: I appreciate this alot, thanks! but it still didn't work.

Comment: @ANDEUS I see. Can you try making a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Working on it, I'll send it ASAP.

Comment: On second thought, I'll just try to solve it myself since I really want to improve. Still, thanks for the help!

Comment: @ANDEUS No worries. Good luck. If you change your mind or need help, feel free to ping me again here in a comment.

Comment: Just pinging you again to tell you that I've fixed it, painstakingly took several hours but it was worth it. The problem lies in just 1 line of code, and it somehow imperatively messed up the entire code, apparently it was referencing the user variable even if it was a null value. Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: @ANDEUS Great, glad you got it sorted out. Cheers.